# Factorization of symmetric positive matrix

Tags: positive-definite, symmetric-matrices, cholesky-decomposition

I have the following question:
Let $A$ be a symmetric positive definite real matrix. Then we are asked to show that there exits two matrices, $C$ and $D$ where $C$ is lower triangular with $1$s in the diagonal and $D$ is diagonal so that:

$$
A=CDC^T
$$

The existence of this decomposition should follow from Cholesky decomposition, taking $D=\mathcal{I}$.

However, we are then asked if this decomposition is unique. It would seems so, but how does one actually prove it?

Comment: I don't you would be allowed to use Cholesky decomposition as that is a decomposition over complex matrices. i.e. When $A=CC^{*}$ where $C^*$ is not just the transpose but also you conjugate the entries. Not just that but the diagonal entries need not be $1$ in the Cholesky decomposition.

Comment: You can use Cholesky in the real case as well. Then it's just $C^T$ instead of $C^*$.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, I view this as applying certain row and column operations to $A$ to get $D$.

The row and column operations that are allowed are

1. Add a multiple of row $i$ to row $j$.
2. Then, add a multiple of column $i$ to column $j$.

Here the $i$ and $j$ are the same indices in 1 and 2. We have to do the same operation on the row and column. This is effectively doing $EAE^T$ for some elementary matrix $E$ and if we compose all of the elementary matrices we get $C$.

Note that this is not the same as elementary row and column operations; we don't switch rows/columns nor multiply by units. These two operations change the determinant of the matrix by a unit. In that sense, it's like a stricter version of Smith normal form but that's fine as our matrix $A$ is symmetric so things are easier.

I hope it's clear how you obtain your diagonal $D$. Firstly, you clear all the entries of your first column and row except the diagonal entry.

i.e. Add $A_{1,j}/A_{1,1}$ multiples of (row/column) $1$ to (row/column) $i$.

**Why does this give uniqueness?**

If I follow the algorithm, there ought to be one decomposition (none of the steps above give non-uniqueness of any sort). But perhaps, some other clever trick gives me another decomposition and I want to check they are the same.

So suppose $A=C_1 D_1 C_1^T=C_2 D_2 C_2^T$.

Observe that $(C_2^{-1}C_1) D_1 (C_2^{-1} C_1)^T=D_2$.

Actually, multiplying a upper triangular matrix with $1$s along the diagonal with another upper triangular matrix with $1$ along the diagonal should give another matrix of the same form. (Not quite the same notion, but it's the subgroup of a Borel subgroup of $GL_n(F)$. )

Same goes for the lower triangular matrices. So can I have two distinct diagonal matrices, $D_1, D_2$ such that $C D_1 C^T=D_2$ where $C$ is a lower triangular matrix with $1$ on the diagonal?

Here we have, $C^{-1} D_2= D_1 C^T$.

Since $C$ is lower triangular, $C^{-1}$ is lower triangular as well.
And a diagonal matrix is also lower triangular. So, the L.H.S. is lower triangular. But for similar reasons, the right hand side is right triangular.

That means we have a diagonal matrix on both sides of the equality. If $C^{-1}D_1$ is diagonal, then $C^{-1}$ must be a diagonal matrix as well (because diagonal matrices form a multiplicative group).

But $C$ must have all $1$ along the diagonal. Thus, it must be the identity. That means, $D_1=D_2$.

Comment: So, you just do Gauss decomposition, and because of symmetry $C^T$ "clears up" the upper side.

Comment: Yet, the part I'm interested is uniquess, which I don't see how it follows from what you said.

Answer (score 1):

I will only show the uniqueness since you say the rest is clear. I will use the fact $D$ is not only diagonal, but diagonal with nonzero entries. This is necessarily the case since if $D$ had zero entries, then $A$ would be only positive *semidefinite*.

Essentially, the uniqueness is because every step of Cholesky factorization is necessary to compute the decomposition. Formally, the uniqueness can be shown inductively, with the induction hypothesis that the $k\times k$ principal submatrices of $C$ and $D$ are uniquely determined. The $k=1$ case just corresponds to the fact that we must have $D_{11} = A_{11}$ (check this!).

Let's do the inductive step. Suppose that the $k\times k$ principal submatrix of $C$ and $D$ are uniquely determined. Let $(\cdot)_j$ denote the $j\times j$ principal submatrix. Block partition $A_{k+1}$, $C_{k+1}$, and $D_{k+1}$ as

$$
A_{k+1} = \begin{bmatrix} A_k & a \\ a^\top & \alpha \end{bmatrix}, \quad C_{k+1} = \begin{bmatrix} C_k & 0 \\ c^\top &1\end{bmatrix}, \quad D_{k+1} = \begin{bmatrix} D_k & 0 \\ 0^\top & \delta \end{bmatrix}.
$$

By the lower triangularity of $C$, we have $A_{k+1} = C_{k+1} D_{k+1} C_{k+1}^\top$. Thus

$$
\begin{bmatrix} A_k & a \\ a^\top & \alpha \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} C_k & 0 \\ c^\top &1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} D_k & 0 \\ 0^\top & \delta \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} C_k^\top & c \\ 0^\top &1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} C_kD_kC_k^\top & C_kD_kc \\ c^\top D_kC_k^\top & c^\top D_k c + \delta\end{bmatrix},
$$

By comparing (1,2) entries, we thus have the condition $C_kD_kc = a$. But $C_k$ and $D_k$ are invertible since $D_k$ is nonzero diagonal and $C_k$ is unit lower triangular. Thus $c$ is uniquely determined and equal to $c = D_k^{-1}C_k^{-1}a$. Then by comparing (2,2) entries, we have $c^\top D_kc + \delta = \alpha$ so $\delta$ is necessarily $\delta = \alpha - c^\top D_kc$. Thus $C_{k+1}$ and $D_{k+1}$ are uniquely determined, and the induction argument is complete.

Comment: Nice! This also gives a proof of existence, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, it does (except for the point of establishing that $D$ will always have nonzero entries).